# jQuery slide and show/hide divs

Tags: jquery, if-statement, show-hide, slide

http://jsfiddle.net/VCUz4/1/

Above is part of a website I am designing. The usual jQuery slide functions work fine but I would like to take it a step further.

Upon clicking one of the release images a div appears showing larger artwork, tracklisting and some other information. When this is open if another release is clicked I would like the old section to hide and the new section to replace it immediately. At the minute I am having trouble with my jQuery.

If .length > 1 the content appears as I would like but if it is 0 the initial content doesn't slide, it just appears but you can swap between the releases. This is the first time I've tried to create my own script as you can probably tell and to be honest the original implementation of just having the sections slide up or down over each other was sufficient but I am wanting to better my work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change your condition:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

    $('#amy, #harris').hide();                        

    $('#link2').click(function() {
        if ($("#harris").is(":visible")) {
            $("#harris").hide();
            $("#amy").show();
        }
        else $('#amy').slideDown(500);

        return false;
    });

    $('#link1').click(function() {
        if ($("#amy").is(":visible")) {
            $("#amy").hide();
            $("#harris").show();
        }
        else $('#harris').slideDown(500);

        return false;
    });  

});
```

Don't check the length of the results of your selector. Both `#harris` and `#amy` are always in the DOM, so the true condition will always be entered.

**Updated example**: http://jsfiddle.net/uwmtN/

Comment: Ahh! I wondered why that was the case but you've explained it well and it makes sense now. Brilliant, thanks for the help.